# Convert string of date format to string of another date format

Tags: c#

I want to convert a string of date format to a string with another format.

The string DateOfBirth could be in different formats such as:

- 01/15/2017
- 01-15-2017
- 1.15.2017
- 1.5.2017

I want to convert it to another pattern that I get it as parameter.

```
public string ConvertStringDateFormat(string date, string convertToDateFormat)
{
}
```

Let's assume that date = "01/15/2017" and convertToDateFormat = "YYYY/MM/DD". How could I change it to the new format?

The problem for me was to do it generic so that it will accept any parametrs.

I thought that I can convert date to DateTime and then to use ToString with the format but can you offer any better idea?

Comment: Converting to a DateTime and using the culture would be easiest, if you wanted an alternative you could also use a series of regexs to match the input and break it down into parts for your output.

Comment: Lookup on locale settings https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact` has an overload that takes multiple formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public string ConvertStringDateFormat(string date, string convertToDateFormat)
{
    return Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(date),convertToDateFormat);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Parse to `DateTime` and then back to `String`:

```
public string ConvertStringDateFormat(string date, string convertToDateFormat) {
  return DateTime
    .ParseExact(date,
       new string[] { "M/d/yyyy", "M-d-yyyy", "M.d.yyyy" },
       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
       DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal)
    .ToString(convertToDateFormat); // convertToDateFormat = @"yyyy\/MM\/dd" for YYYY/MM/DD
}
```

Comment: Is your final `ToString` format correct as you use `@` and `\/`?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: '\' *escapes* '/' symbol as a separator

Comment: Actually it should be `ToString(convertToDateFormat)`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Oh I didn't realise the `/` was a special character in the to string call

Answer (score 2):

i think this will work :

```
   (Convert.ToDateTime(date)).ToString(convertToDateFormat)
```