# Convert string to string(datetime) in EST

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, datetime-format

I have string in **"Mon, 20 Mar 2021 14:04:48 +0000"**
and I want to convert it as **"20 Mar 2021 | 14:04 PM"**

I want to convert the string as it is but it was appearing differently in my local and server.

Comment: What is `string(datetime)`?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40911989/3181933) answers your question.

Comment: Where are you seeing this string?  Are you sure it's a string and not a DateTime?  *it was appearing differently in my local and server* suggests it's a DateTime being displayed in a different format on your server

Comment: DateTime and DateTimeOffset are binary value, not strings. They have no format, precisely because they're binary values. Formats apply only when they're displayed to users or serialized to text, reports etc.

Comment: `it was appearing differently in my local and server.` what are the summer time rules on your server? The US went into summer time this week. The UK goes into summer time on March 28. Using strings to save date and time, or assuming the offset doesn't change is a *very* bad idea. It's not the server that's changing the time, it's the code that handles dates the wrong way

Comment: What do you really want to do? The first string uses an offset. The second is local time. Whose local time though? The server's ? The client's? There's no guarantee they're on the same timezone or use the same DST rules. Each machine's local time is correct for that machine and doesn't need "fixing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `20 Mar 2021` is **Saturday**, not **Monday**, let's correct it. Then you can `ParseExact` to get `DateTime` and finally represent it in the required format with a help of `ToString()`:

```
  string source = "Sat, 20 Mar 2021 14:04:48 +0000";

  string result = DateTime
    .ParseExact(source, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    .ToUniversalTime()
    .ToString("dd MMM yyyy' | 'HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Notes:

- It seems that you want to obtain *Universal* (not *Local*) time, that's why I've added `ToUniversalTime()`
- `14:04 PM` looks *strange* for me (`14:04` and `02:04 PM` are much more frequent formats); put `hh` instead of `HH` to have `02:04 PM`

Comment: 20th March is Friday in the Julian calendar.

Comment: @Scroog1: but still not *Monday* ;)

Comment: I'm sure there's a calendar somewhere where it is :)

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to be manipulating the timezone information, then use [Noda Time](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime).

If that's your exact text format, and the dates and times are what you want, you can convert it manually:

```
var input = "Mon, 20 Mar 2021 14:04:48 +0000";

var dateParts = input.Split(' ');
var timeParts  = dateParts[4].Split(':');
var amPm = int.Parse(timeParts[0]) < 12 ? "AM" : "PM";
var output = $"{dateParts[1]} {dateParts[2]} {dateParts[3]} | {timeParts[0]}:{timeParts[1]} {amPm}";

System.Console.WriteLine(output); // "20 Mar 2021 | 14:04 PM"
```

Or, if you are feel adventurous, use a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-5.0).

Comment: This guarantees the wrong result for the next 6 months, as countries have started switching to DST.

Comment: There was no specification of if the +0000 would change in the string or outside it.

Comment: Presumably "Mon, 20 Mar 2021 14:04:48 +0100" would want to still be "20 Mar 2021 | 14:04 PM", so the code would work.

Comment: Why make that assumption at all? Local time is local time, not local time if it was still winter. If that date was `29 Mar` in the UK, you'd need to use +1. In the US it's already summer time

Comment: I'm not making any assumptions. The question just says convert this string to this other one. It didn't say the string was wrong, only that the server was changing it to something else.

Comment: The `other one` is local time. Which always assumes a specific timezone and offset. That's what causes the problem, not the server. The timezone remains the same, while the offset changes. The server isn't changing it to something else. The OP is making the same assumption as this answer, that the offset remains unchanged. That's wrong, and it just changed.

Comment: To be slightly pedantic, the question doesn't state the date/time is different between local and server, only that the string is different. They could be the same date/time in different formats. It could be a different culture problem.